# How to get Sinon's fakeServer to respond to jQuery.ajax calls when in Mocha and Node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I've looked at a lot of answers here, blog posts there, issues in Sinon's own issue tracker and have not found anything definitive. What I've so far is roughly:

```
import XMLHttpRequest from "xhr2";
...
beforeEach((done) => {
  jsdom.env("<!doctype html><html><body><div></div></body></html>", (error, window) => {
    for (var i in require.cache) {delete require.cache[i];}

    Object.assign(global, _.pick(window, "document", "navigator"));
    global.window = window;
    window.console = global.console;
    document.body.dataset = {};

    ...

    global.$ = require("jquery");
    global.$(() => {
      global.$.support.cors = true;
      global.$.ajaxSettings.xhr = () => {return new XMLHttpRequest();};
      const fakeServer = require("sinon/lib/sinon/util/fake_server").fakeServer;
      global.server = fakeServer.create({autoRespond: true});
      done();
    });
  });
});

...

it("should bloody work!", () => {
  server.respondWith([401, {}, ""]);
  ...
  [some test code that triggers an $.ajax call];
});
```

In the $.ajax error handler, I log the arguments to the $.ajax fail handler and see:

```
jqXHR = { readyState: 0,
  getResponseHeader: [Function],
  getAllResponseHeaders: [Function],
  setRequestHeader: [Function],
  overrideMimeType: [Function],
  statusCode: [Function],
  abort: [Function],
  state: [Function],
  always: [Function],
  then: [Function],
  promise: [Function],
  pipe: [Function],
  done: [Function],
  fail: [Function],
  progress: [Function],
  complete: [Function],
  success: [Function],
  error: [Function],
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Error' }
textStatus = error
errorThrown = [Error]
```

It makes no difference whether I set up the fake server to respond with a 200 and "OK", or fiddle with the .ajax call, all roads lead to a status of 0 and a text of 'Error'.